# How to change the background color of TextEditor like TextField

Tags: swift, swiftui, textfield

```
struct TextView: View {
    @State private var textInput2: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView{
            VStack(spacing: 24){
                TextField("", text: $textInput2)
                    .font(.body)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .padding()
                    .frame(height: 142)
                    .background(Color("3"))
                    .cornerRadius(20)
                    .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                            .stroke(Color.gray.opacity(0.5), lineWidth: 2)
                    )
                
                TextEditor(text: $textInput2)
                    .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
                    .font(.body)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color("3"))
                    .frame(height: 142)
                    .cornerRadius(20)
                    .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                            .stroke(Color.gray.opacity(0.5), lineWidth: 2)
                    )
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }
    }
}
```

I want to change the background color of a `TextEditor`, I tried:

- `.foregroundColor` changed the text color instead of the background color;
- `.background` only changed the surroundings' background color and not the whole `TextEditor` as seen in the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line to `TextEditor`:

```
.scrollContentBackground(.hidden) // <- Hide it
```

Comment: Downside: only available for iOS 16 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

`UITextView` is the base class of `TextEditor`. So you need to change `UITextView`'s background color to clear when initializing the struct, then you can set any color as the background.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    init() {
        UITextView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a modifier that will work for all iOS versions

```
func transparentScrolling() -> some View {
    if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
        return scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
    } else {
        return onAppear {
            UITextView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
        }
    }
}
```

and then add it to your `TextField` or `TextEditor`

```
TextEditor(text: $textString)
.multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
.foregroundColor(.primaryText)
.frame(height: 75)
.transparentScrolling()
```